# Some doubts related to the AOP configuration in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-aop

I am studying for Spring Core certification and I have a doubt related how Spring handle AOP.

Reading the documentation it seems to understand that exist 2 way to obtain AOP in Java:

1. Using **AspectJ** that using byte code modification for aspect weaving offers a full-blown Aspect Oriented Programming language.  (so it seems to me that **AspectJ** is a differnt language that can be integrated with Java to offer it the AOP features).
2. **Spring AOP**: used in Spring framework that uses dynamic proxies for aspect weaving instead the bytecode modification.

So my doubts are mainly the followings:

1) Reading the documentations found the following method to add the **AOP support** to my Spring application:

**USING JAVA CONFIGURATION CLASS:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages=“com.example”)
public class AspectConfig {
    ...
}
```

**USING XML CONFIGURATION:**

```
<beans>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <context:component-scan base-package=“com.example” />
</beans>
```

As you can see in both configurations there is a reference to **AspectJ**:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
```

and

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
```

Why? If Spring use **Spring AOP** instead **AspectJ** why there is a reference to **AspectJ** when I configure AOP in Spring?

2) In the previous examples are show 2 way to configure Spring: by **Java configuration class** and by **XML configuration**. I know that exist a third way to configure a Spring application: by the use of **annotations**. So **exist a way to configure AOP using the annotations?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that these Spring AOP settings with references to AspectJ in their names are indeed more irritating than helpful. I can understand why you are confused. Spring AOP is really a different concept from AspectJ. As you said: dynamic JDK or CGLIB proxies in Spring AOP versus byte code instrumentation during compile or load time in AspectJ. Other differences are:

- AspectJ compile-time weaving needs a special compiler called *Ajc*. It is basically an Eclipse Java compiler *Ecj* enhanced by the aspect weaver which does the instrumentation. In contrast, Spring AOP creates dynamic proxies during runtime.
- In AspectJ there are two syntax variants: native and annotation-based. The former is more elegant and expressive, a superset of Java and definitely needs *Ajc* to be compiled. The latter uses Java annotations and can be compiled with *Javac*, **but** needs the aspect weaver contained both in *Ajc* (compile time) and in the weaving agent *aspectjweaver.jar* (load time) to "finish" them and make them usable during runtime. Both variants need the AspectJ runtime contained in both *aspectjrt.jar* (very small, used for compile-time-woven aspects during runtime) and *aspectjweaver.jar* (much bigger, used for load-time weaving, contains both the runtime and the weaver).
- AspectJ works for any Java class, it does not need or even know about the Spring framework. Spring AOP needs the Spring framework as a foundation, you can only instrument Spring Beans/Components with it, not Spring-agnostic POJOs.
- AspectJ is more efficient because it avoids proxies. But Spring AOP is an optional part of the Spring framework anyway, so if you use Spring and method execution interception of Spring Beans is all you need, it makes perfect sense to use it.
- **Spring AOP uses a subset of the AspectJ pointcut syntax.** Maybe this is the subtle reason why Spring AOP uses AspectJ references, but I still think it was a bad decision to not differentiate the two concepts from one another more clearly with regard to nomenclature. Besides, the common poinctut language subset is defined in a little JAR called *aopalliance.jar* because long ago a so-called "AOP Alliance" has defined that syntax. The dominating and by far most powerful AOP language today is AspectJ, though, so in reality AspectJ (maintained by Eclipse) is the leader in that area, IMO.
- When I say that Spring AOP uses a subset of AspectJ syntax, conversely it means that AspectJ offers a superset. There are more pointcut types such as `call()`, `set()`, `get()` etc. and you have way more options to intercept joinpoints and apply cross-cutting concerns to your code base via advice or inter-type definition.

I do not understand your question #2. The configuration class in your example does use annotations, so there is no third way. ;-) But there is an old, really outdated AOP approach in Spring called interceptors. It is a leftover of an early AOP approach and kind of obsolete nowadays, even though it is still usable.

Both Spring AOP and AspectJ can be configured via XML or annotations within Spring. :-)

Comment: Good answer, I've only every worked with AspectJ with respect to Spring AOP, this answer helped me understand more about how they work together. +1

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I completely understand your question, I think you are asking something like: "If I'm using Spring AOP, why do I see references to AspectJ?"

If that's the case, you should know that Spring is not in *competition* with AspectJ, but rather *leverages* AspectJ for AOP.

See Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

Comment: I disagree, kind of. The Spring framework as such is not in competition with AspectJ because it supports both its own Spring AOP and full-blown AspectJ via configurartion. But the two AOP alternatives are competition for each other insofar as everything you can do with Spring AOP can also be done with AspectJ plus much more. So as soon as the limited feature set of Spring AOP is not enough, you need to use AspectJ. There is nothing keeping you from using AspectJ *only* right from the start, i.e. ignore Spring AOP altogether. So in this respect the two are competitors. Otherwise I agree. :-)

Comment: I can see that perspective as well. I'm just going by what the Spring docs say. Of course, this may just be the Spring folks being diplomatic.

Comment: I would argree that the two AOP frameworks coexist peacefully in Spring. :-) Maybe this is what they mean.